# Angular navigation wizard

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create navigation tools using a wizard for a web application.

So far the wizard is already working with 2 navigation buttons on each page (back/next). There is also a request from the PO to insert a navigation panel on top of the page so users can easily swap between page without having to navigate in the whole site.
For this panel, i use RouterLink to generate link to the specific pages.

There is a slight problem with my implementation still.
When I use the top navigation panel to move between pages then decide to use navigations buttons, my navigation wizard function doesnt get recognized anymore (full text is : this.onNext is not a function at GeneralInfoComponent.next (generalinfo.component.ts:53)).

Here is my code :

**Generalinfo.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EvaluationService } from '../evaluation.service';
import { InfoGeneral } from './model';
import { WizardComponent } from './../wizard/index';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'generalinfo-cmp',
templateUrl: 'generalinfo.component.html'
})

export class GeneralInfoComponent {

@Input() onNext: any;

generalInfo:    InfoGeneral;
form:               FormGroup;
wizard:             ClaimStep;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private evaluationService: EvaluationService
) {
        this.initForm();
        this.generalInfo = evaluationService.getGeneralInfo();
}


initForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        generalInfo: this.fb.group({
            consultantFirstName: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantLastName: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantPhone: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantEmail: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantWishedJob: ['', Validators.required],
            managerName: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantExperience: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantMinRemuneration: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantMaxRemuneration: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantAvailableDate: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantInterviewDate: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantInterviewHour: ['', Validators.required],
            consultantComment: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    });
}

next() {
        this.onNext();
}
}
```

**RandomPage.component.html** (to show the navigation panel links)

```
[...]
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/evaluation/generalinfo/']" skipLocationChange><span class="label">✓</span></a>
[...]
```

**wizard.component.html**

```
<generalinfo-cmp *ngIf="wizard.currentStep === 1" [onNext]="onNext"></generalinfo-cmp>
<matrice-cmp *ngIf="wizard.currentStep === 2" [onBack]="onBack" [onNext]="onNext"></matrice-cmp>
<entretienrh-cmp *ngIf="wizard.currentStep === 3" [onBack]="onBack" [onNext]="onNext" ></entretienrh-cmp>
<entretienmgr-cmp *ngIf="wizard.currentStep === 4" [onBack]="onBack" [onNext]="onNext" ></entretienmgr-cmp>
<entretiendir-cmp *ngIf="wizard.currentStep === 5" [onBack]="onBack" [onNext]="onNext" ></entretiendir-cmp>
<proposition-cmp *ngIf="wizard.currentStep === 6" [onBack]="onBack"></proposition-cmp>
```

**wizard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject  } from '@angular/core';
import {  ClaimStep } from './wizard.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'wizard-cmp',
  templateUrl: 'wizard.component.html',
  providers: [ClaimStep],
})

export class WizardComponent  {

wizard: ClaimStep;
constructor(private claimStep: ClaimStep) {
    this.wizard = claimStep;
}

onNext = () => {
    this.wizard.addStep();
}

onBack = () => {
    this.wizard.subtractStep();
}

onSwitch = () => {
            console.log(this.wizard.getCurrentStep());
    }
}
```

**wizard.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ClaimStep {
currentStep: number;

constructor() {
    this.currentStep = 1;
}

addStep(): number {
    return this.currentStep++;
}

subtractStep() {
    this.currentStep = this.currentStep - 1;
    return this.currentStep;
}

getCurrentStep() {
    return this.currentStep;
}
}
```

Thanks for any input on this

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having issues with the `this` context.

Can you try using this instead:

```
onNext = (() => {
    this.wizard.addStep();
}).bind(this);

onBack = (() => {
    this.wizard.subtractStep();
}).bind(this);
```

or maybe this (instead of the previous suggestion):

```
... [onNext]="onNext.bind(this)" ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, any of the suggestion works with my case.